# menu hiding to include progress bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-menu, android-progressbar

Hi i have created an activity which is used for downloading and uploading. I have used a menu(items:download, upload, delete, quit). But when i press the download button, download work begins, but the menu button does not disappear till this task completes. It will be frustrating for user without any notification. How to hide a menu immediately after pressing it and how to include a progress bar, which notify user regarding download and upload task.

Hi i have methods:

```
 void downloadFile(SmbFile file,String desPath)
 void downloadFolder(SmbFile folder,String tempStore)
 void uploadFile(File file,SmbFile destination)
 void uploadFolder(File f,SmbFile destination)
```

please tell me where to add these methods in below code which extends async task...

```
 class helper extends AsyncTask
{

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

 }
```

Comment: Please use thread or Asynctask to download and upload task . So it can't hangs your UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use 2 difference type parameters, so you can use the constructor (or use getter, setter for the parameters you want to pass):

```
public class Helper extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

//The filed you want to pass
private SmbFile file;
private String desPath;
private SmbFile folder;
private String tempStore;
private File file;
private SmbFile destination;

//Create setter

public void setFile(SmbFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public void setDesPath(String desPath) {
    this.desPath = desPath;
}

public void setFolder(SmbFile folder) {
    this.folder = folder;
}

public void setTempStore(String tempStore) {
    this.tempStore = tempStore;
}

public void setFile(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}


public void setDestination(SmbFile destination) {
    this.destination = destination;
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    //check flag to excute exactly method
    switch (params[0]) {
    case 0:
                    //Call your download file method
        downloadFile(file,desPath);
        break;
    case 1:
                   //Call your download folder method
        downloadFolder(folder,tempStore);
   //etc...
    default:
        break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

When the download menu  is pressed, you can call async task:

```
//Download the file
Helper helper = new Helper();
//set file and des path for download file
helper.setFile(your_file);
helper.setDesPath(your_despath);
//Excute the download file method
helper.excute(0);

//Download the folder
 //set file and des path for download file
helper.setFolder(your_folder);
helper.setTempStore(your_tempStore);
//Excute the download folder method
helper.excute(1);

//etc...
```

*Note*: Please read carefully [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to understand how to use AsyncTask.

Comment: could u pls explain this line AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>?

Comment: And i am new to android..could u pls elaborate the the code by adding another 4 functions?

Answer (score 0):

I think your your UI is blocked because downloading taking place in UI Thread. So move your downloading process to background thread. It solves your problem.